# How to add a simple routing rule to traefik

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to get started with traefik in the hopes I can replace my current reverse proxy (pound) with traefik.

How do I add a simple routing rule so that mysubdomain.mydomain.com routes to http://192.168.x.x:8080?

I'm following the [quickstart here](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/#1-launch-trfik-tell-it-to-listen-to-docker). I created the following docker compose yml file and started it with `docker-compose up -d reverse-proxy`

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    image: traefik #The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker #Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     #The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" #The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock #So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
```

Great, the container is running, but now what? How would I go about adding the simply routing rule?

If my backend web service isn't running one of these [supported backends](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/#supported-backends) will it not work? Surely traefik can simply route http requests to any http backend right?

For example my backend web service is a web interface for my synology NAS at home. Traefik should be able to route this right? If so, how?